# The ModifiedOWSDATE do not match with LastModifiedDate

Tags: content-search-web-part, sorting

We are using SP2013 on-premise enterprise. There is a CSWP show latest 20 updated document or webpages on entire farm.

First, the search query is sorted by "LastModifiedDate". Secondly, the CSWP display template is displaying "ModifiedOWSDATE". In the template it contains following code:

```
var line3 = $getItemValue(ctx, "ModifiedOWSDATE");
 try
 {
  var parsedDate = new Date(line3.inputValue);
  line3 = parsedDate.format('dd-MM-yyyy');
 }
```

After some tests, I found the document which have last modified date 11-May will be sorted as 5-Nov.

Although I figure out the cause, I don't know how to check or fix. Could you please advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As ModifiedOWSDATE is a STRING, you will need to parse it into a date format. Now, check your machine Regional settings (and even SP server settings), client not matching server for the date format as you say 11/05 is swapped to 05/11...?